How to achieve this arc design in flutter
I am trying to create a custom design using arcs in Flutter, but I am unable to achieve the desired results. Here's what I have attempted so far:
I want to create a design similar to where the arcs are styled in a specific way.
Used CustomPainter to draw arcs.
Experimented with Canvas methods like drawArc and drawPath to achieve the design.
Adjusted the arc angles, starting points, and radii, but I couldn't get the exact shape.
(https://i.sstatic.net/i3py0gj8.png)

Please share the related code.
